# Differents ways to represent a natural number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am lookin for the differents ways to represent a natural number just like in this example: the number 4 can be expressed in these following 8 ways:

1+1+1+1
2+1+1
1+2+1
1+1+2
3+1
1+3
2+2
4

I have been able to verify that the representation up to n={1,2,3,4,5} corresponds to $2^{n-1}$
but i wish i could prove it for n

Comment: These are called [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) and there are $2^{n-1}$ of them (see the link).

Comment: You may also be interested in Young tableaux https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau

Comment: Thank you @lulu thats was very useful!

Comment: I would be inclined to include "iv" as a way to indicate "4" as well as "$\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot$".